# Unable to extend desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop, amd-radeon, tv

I'm trying to hook up my TV to my computer as a gaming/multimedia center but I'm having troubles setting it up.

I have a custom built machine running Windows 7 RC.
It has an ATI Radeon 4800 video card with 2 dvi output and 1 S-video output.
I have an s-video to composite adapter that connects to my tv.  (It's an old TV with only Cable, composite, and s-video connections).

I can switch the desktop to my TV without a problem, but I can't duplicate or extend my desktop onto it.

I've installed the latest drivers and Catalyst Control Center, but it won't let it work any more readily than Windows would.

Any suggestions?
Would using an s-video cable instead of the adapter change anything?  (The only reason I use the adapter is because it came with the graphics card)

(Edit)
I installed the latest drivers and I can now duplicate the screen (show on one monitor and on the TV), but I still can't extend the desktop.

Comment: how you switch between desktop and the TV ?

Comment: Time to buy a nice new TV with an HDMI in, even if you get it working through your existing connections it's going to look rough.

Comment: @Revolter I switch by using display settings and display only on monitor 1 for computer, only on monitor 2 for TV

Comment: @Col I just built a custom high end gaming computer and I'm a college student.  The combination means I don't have money for a new TV.  Even If I did, I would have to be pluging and unpluging all the time since I have a Dual monitor setup and both DVI outputs are used.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching your LCD display to the other DVI port.  This fixed the problem on my ATI video card.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/173976-dual-monitors-1-tv-possible-4800-series.html), **it seems that the ATI 4800 series does not support a triple video out setup.**

I'm not sure how to check on Catalyst, but on NVidia cards, it will tell you under multiple display settings that the card does not handle more than two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems extendind my desktop to tv after installing new ati catalyst control center.
Then I noticed my secondary display adapter was turned off from device manager.
Enabling it solved the problem in windows xp.